# Binary data storage scheme (saving user-uploaded files)

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles, binary-data

In our app we are currently saving binary data to the database (terrible, I know; but this is legacy stuff and it wasn't my decision). We're trying to migrate this data out to an external device and I'm trying to come up with a scheme to save these files.

We have multiple tenants, I'd like to have a directory per tenant. My scheme for that is to build path using the first-three letters of the tenant. So if you had a tenant called `apple`, its files would be at `/a/p/p/apple`. Within these directories, I will save the files. For the files, I want to generate a random 6-character alphanumeric name (only lowercase characters for the time being because internal reasons). So if we generate a file name called `6a8jxo`, it will stored as `<tenant>/6/a/6/6a8jxo`. With this strategy, each tenant can have a maximum of approximately 916 billion unique files (not that we're attempting to save that many), with a maximum of 46,656 files per directory. If I go for a 5-character name, we will have a maximum of 60.5 billion unique files with 1,296 files per directory.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach? I realize that certain directories may only contain one or two files, but in my mind that is not a huge problem.

My colleague doesn't want to do it this way; he wants to use an autoincremented field in the database and then base the directory structure on the hex-value (I assume 32-bit) of that instead of using the tenant. With his strategy the hex value would be used as follows: the file will be stored in the directory located at `<tenant>/aa/bbb` where `aa` is the first two characters (most significant nibbles) of the hex value, and `bbb` is the next three. His reasoning is that he only wants to create new directories when one fills up instead of having numerous, partially-filled directories.

This approach introduces numerous difficulties on the code side of things and I don't see having completely-filled directories as an argument that justifies the extra effort required to do this.

Are there any other strategies or approaches I haven't considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main thing you haven't considered is the likelihood of collisions in your random file names.

With such small names, you only have `36 ^ 6 = 2,176,782,336` unique files, which means you are likely to get a collision before hitting 50,000 files (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) - not a huge number (and of course there's always the chance of getting one much earlier).

I like your colleague's approach simply because it guarantees unique names, regardless of how it affects the filesystem.

If you absolutely don't want to rely on the database to generate a consistent sequence, you can use [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for the names.

You also seem to be planning for very deep trees - how many files (and tenants) do you expect to have? A reasonable rule of thumb is to have 10,000 files (actual, not just possible) per directory, and probably more with modern filesystems. Three levels of sub-directories is almost certainly overkill.

Also, if you do need to split the tenants into multiple directories, hash them first (or use database ids) - using natural names can lead to very unbalanced "buckets" (probably not a big issue here, but it doesn't cost anything to do it correctly).

Finally, how big are the files? Depending on your actual use-case, storing them in the database may be a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: This is the route we ended up going. A few of the concerns I had regarding the I'd (which were only really related to idiosyncrasies in our code) were resolved.